# Business paying back debt to individuals

Tags: united-states, investing, debt, limited-liability-company

I have a single member LLC (Missouri, United States) that I started a few years ago. We received approximately $20,000 in funding from family and friends, of which I did not fully understand the implications of at the time that it was done. It was never declared as any form of "investment" and did not grant any ownership of the company. It was money that was simply borrowed from people around us.

We are now at the point to be able to start paying back this money to the individuals. My question(s) now is the best way to pay them back.

1. If we pay back exactly what was paid in, will we need to record these payments as income for the individuals (W9s) to where they have to pay taxes on it?
2. We also plan on paying recurring percentages of business profits to these individuals after the initial amount is paid back, so what would be the implications and requirements to do that as well?
3. Would payments to these individuals (either type) be an expense for the business to write off, or would they be taxed for us as well?

Finding the answers to these has been a little difficult since these were all personal friends/family, not banks or venture capitalists.

Comment: Regarding your 3rd bullet point, interest payments would be taxable to the recipient (and an expense to your business) the principle of the loan is not taxable, you’re just returning their money, the same way it was not taxable to you when you received it; it wasn’t income it was a loan.

Comment: Probably doesn't change the answer, but I'm curious: you mention "single member LLC" but also use the pronouns "we" and "us". How many owners are there?

Comment: Was the money loaned to you personally, and you used the money to start the business, or was the money loaned to the business? If it was the business, does the business accounting show liabilities for the loans, or does it just appear as if you personally seeded the business with $20K?

Comment: Are the payments from revenue EXPECTED by the people who loaned to you, or are you simply being a good friend and paying them because you feel it's the right thing to do?  What EXACTLY were the terms the money was loaned to you under - "just give it back when you can", "You're gonna cut me in on profits, right?" - what did those conversations look like, because your post muddies the waters quite a bit on this and makes it hard to give you a clear answer, as the threads below show! (grin)

Comment: Generally speaking, repayment of a loan is not deductible to the payor and not income to the payee. Interest on the loan is a deductible expense and is income.

Answer (score 2):

If it did not grant any ownership in the company, then it was a loan. A loan with "recurring percentages of business profits" sounds like a type of revenue share loan — let's call it a [profit share loan](https://republic.co/revenue-share).

If the terms haven't been discussed yet, then choose the [terms](https://localstake.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/215567847-What-are-the-standard-terms-for-a-revenue-share-loan-) that make sense for all parties.

For a revenue/profit share loan, the 'share' payments are considered to be loan interest. Interest income for the recipient means that your business can [issue a 1099](https://localstake.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/212618158-How-is-a-revenue-share-loan-taxed-). Your business can also deduct the loan interest as a business expense.

Comment: Why is the topic of gift tax relevant when repaying loans?

Comment: @YoshiOnimusha - hmm, the situation seems perfectly clear.  They made a loan to purchases a revenue stream.  Nothing more to it.

Comment: There are a couple points of confusion here. (1) there is no gift involved at all (2) "interest" is mentioned a couple times, such as in the final sentence; there is no interest involved at all.  It's just an ordinary, simple, everyday, commonplace loan-for-revenue.

Comment: Thanks, rereading the original post, it's likely that this is a "profit share loan." Changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: Hi @OrangeCoast-reinstateMonica - I was wondering:  *For a revenue/profit share loan, the 'share' payments are considered to be loan interest*  - in my experience (both sides) that has not been the case.  Can you tell where you got that from or why it came to mind?  It's simply not interest and has no connection to interest.   Note that: * We plan on paying recurring percentages of business profits...* to the people.  This just has no connection to interest.  Continued ...

Comment: Say I buy 20% of your business from you. I now get certain payments (from profits etc.) forever. When I say "buy" note that there are various ways I can do that. It's common that programmers get a % of a business as a payment.  It's common to pay money as a payment. It's common to "offer expertise" (like the "sharks") to get the 20%. And indeed it's completely common to capitalize a business, or for example, advance materials, shipping or manufacturing to a business, in exchange for a %. In all cases, "I now get certain payments (from profits etc.) forever". That has no connection to interest.

Comment: From OP, "..did not grant any ownership of the company. It was money that was simply borrowed.."

Comment: Indeed note that!   I Bill buys from Steve a revenue stream from a company, and what Bill is doing in return is making a loan to the company.  Note that *indeed* the terms of that *loan* could indeed include interest, or, the loan could be interest free.  In that case those payment would indeed be interest.  But completely unrelated to that, the payment of the revenue stream is unrelated to interest.

Comment: @OrangeCoast-reinstateMonica yes but (sorry, as I was just about to type) they simply bought a revenue stream (as in my Bill/Steve example!) **"We also plan on paying recurring percentages of business profits [forever] to these individuals"** couldn't be clearer.  It's not interest.

Comment: "But completely unrelated to that, the payment of the revenue stream is unrelated to interest." - Saying it's unrelated doesn't make it so. Profit share was not offered to random pedestrians; it was offered to the lenders only. That makes the profit share related to the loan; in fact it makes it interest (for accounting and tax purposes). See my links

Comment: Hi @OrangeCoast-reinstateMonica I'm really sorry, but you're plain wrong here.  The mods don't like "back and fores", and I'd only be repeating myself:  (1) it's totally commonplace to buy revenue stream (or indeed per-sale payments) in exchange for offering a loan, L, to a company.  (2) The loan itself, L, may or may not have interest payments.  (3)  If you then get (let's say) $2 per item sold forever, or (let's say) a certain payment based on profit (or, some other business factor) forever, item (3) has no connection to interest.

Comment: {Your statement, "Profit share was not offered to random pedestrians" .. is simply wrong.  It would be common that they also offer profit share to:  Programmers; Suppliers;  Experts;  "Shark-type" industry connections, "friends who helped", and so on.}  {Or for example, in Facebooks case, they had to ultimately compensate "the people they ripped off the idea from at the beginning".}

Comment: I think what makes it confusing (at least for simpletons like me!) is that the OP doesn't state exactly the circumstances of the loans - did the people expect to receive just what they loaned and made the loans as a favor, were there terms of *ANY* kind attached to the money, etc.  The post doesn't make this clear.  If I loan someone money as a favor, expecting nothing back, and they decide to go above and beyond by paying me extra, how would that be accounted for?  In that case I didn't "buy a revenue stream", I simply made a no-interest loan to a friend.  What then?

Comment: hi @SRiverNet - I find that normal.  For example, I once did X for a corporation and they simply a bit later flat out rote me a cheque (above and beyond the agreed terms). The taxman doesn't care at all, and there are no forms for, "what we agreed beforehand".  All you "enter in in your costs item in the tax form" is what you paid out. Here, it would make zero difference to the paperwork if, the OP had stated "ex post facto, I decided to pay them $5000 a year for their help", or, "we had agreed they would get $5000 a year". It's irrelevant to form-filling, in the US tax milieu.

Comment: @fattie, gotcha.  Thanks for the explanation on that! (smile)

Comment: To literally answer your question, in the US, *"If I loan someone money as a favor, expecting nothing back, and they decide to go above and beyond by paying me extra, how would that be accounted for?"*  This is commonplace. Some illustrators work for us for $5,000 and I pay them $10,000 instead.  It's a non-issue to the taxman. All that matters is "I paid them X".  Say, to be a smartass, I had a PI dig you up IRL and had my company pay you $1,000.  It's just a payment - end of story. You'd have to include it in your income for the year, and for us it would be a cost.

Comment: @SRiverNet , yes it's quite confusing always to me, not being originally from the US, that the IRS is "utterly value free".  I mean the classic example is you can write in "$50,000 income from illegal activities" and it's just another computer entry  :) :)  This sort of shit just doesn't go down in other nations!  :O  Jesu

Answer (score -1):

1 - It seems that they gave you a loan, interest free, *in exchange for* some benefit (in fact, a specified revenue stream). (There is no "gift" involved whatsoever. It's a completely normal business deal, as if you sold them a packet of gum.) So far there is nothing to do, say or report.

2 - Yes of course, obviously. If business B pays person P ten bucks in that situation, that is a ten buck cost, expense, for the business; and it is ten bucks income for the person.  Obviously.

3 - Ditto, see (2).

Comment: Your point #2 is a little misleading. If businesses B pays person P ten bucks,it could also be profit distribution or a dividend,both of which would be taxed differently than how you seem to imply.

Comment: hi @TooTea !  However, as it says clearly *"it is ten bucks income for the person"*.  Which is a fact.  Of course, different people will pay tax on that ten dollars (or an any ten dollars) in drastically different ways.  On the other side, I (myself) don't see any way you could get away with calling this a dividend?  It's just a payment for a service - exactly like, say, a royalty per unit sold, or just any plain payment for a service given.  i think!!

Comment: @TooTea the investors are not owners so they can't receive distributions (or dividends). From the question, it's not exactly clear (yet) how the investors will be paid.

Comment: @TTT, you know, it is pretty clear:  **We also plan on paying recurring percentages of business profits to these individuals**.  It's totally commonplace that party A makes a loan to a business *{which in itself may or may not have interest}* in return for purchasing a revenue stream, or often some sort of "per sale" amount.  This is that commonplace arrangement.

Comment: @Fattie I think it's clear *what* they want to do, but it's not clear (at least to me) *how* they will do it. I don't know of many options for a Single Member LLC to write checks to individuals who aren't owners or employees. 1099 contractor maybe?

Comment: Hmm, I do that (or have it done to me) all the time. I may be misunderstanding what you mean. {I don't see any difference if it is a self-employed concern, or, a corporation.}

Comment: It makes a difference for how it's reported and whether or not it's taxable. For example, distributions payments are not deductible by the business or taxed as income by the recipients. Interest payments and contractor payments would be deductible, and declared as income by recipients, but the reporting forms and thresholds are different (1099-INT, 1099-MISC, 1099-NEC, etc.) I'd say the discussion around your point #2 is probably not needed since the investors *can't* get distributions or dividends, so I can't think of any way (as a Single Member LLC) that your point #2 could be wrong.

Comment: If anything, I might disagree with point #3, but I'm not sure. I don't think I understand the third question: "Would payments to these individuals (either type)..." What does "either type" refer to?

Comment: I don't wanna annoy the Hardworking Mods with discussion, and (B) the bloody question is so confused anyway!  :)   I may ask some of these questions more clearly as another question, leading to more discussion!  Cheers !!!  :)

Comment: Please don't add text to your answer complaining about downvotes. It's ok to refer to another answer to disagree with it if you want to (without making it into personal statements).